# Docker containers can't write inside cifs share

Tags: docker, docker-compose, synology, nas, cifs

I have a docker compose for a media server i'm building using multiple containers, i want these containers to be able to R/W a cifs share mounted on host, after trying multiple ways i can't seem get them to write.
here's the mounted share : /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.X.X/Media /mnt/Media cifs cache=loose,credentials=/root/.smbcrd,vers=3.0 0 0
```

and here's one of the multiple containers docker compose :

```
 emby:
image: linuxserver/emby
container_name: emby
environment:
  - PUID=998
  - PGID=100
  - TZ=Europe/Paris
  - UMASK_SET=022 #optional
volumes:
  - /mnt/Media/Configs/Emby:/config
  - /mnt/Media/Series:/data/series
  - /mnt/Media/Films:/data/movies
ports:
  - 8096:8096
  - 8920:8920 
restart: unless-stopped
```

I'm learning docker and i don't think mounting the cifs share inside every container is the solution,do i need to mount the share in volumes section of my docker compose ?,the share is a synology nas.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CIFS Possibilities for Docker

### Let Container mount (bad approach)

```
services:
  name:
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH
    security_opt:
      - "apparmor=unconfined"
```

Dockerfile:
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "mount.sh" ]`

mount.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /mnt/whatever
mount -v -t cifs -o username=xx,password=xx,vers=SMB-Version-Number,dir_mode=0744,file_mode=0744 //IP/Path /mnt/whatever

<start your container logic>
```

Bad approach due to very bad security, but in some use-cases could be helpful.

### Let docker mount

```
services:
  name:
     volumes:
      - my_mount:/mnt/whatever

volumes:
  my_mount: 
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=xx,password=xx,vers=SMB-Version-Number
      device: //IP/Path
```

### Let host mount

```
mount -t cifs -o username=xx,password=xx, \               
  uid=dockeruid,forceuid, \
  gid=dockergid,forcegid, \                  
  file_mode=744,dir_mode=744 //IP/Path /mnt/whatever
```

run docker containers then with this user:

```
services:
  name:
    user: "dockeruid:dockergid"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/whatever:/mnt/whatever
```